# Can't establish secured connection with SOAP unistream

Tags: php, security, curl, soap, soap-client

I have problem with interaction with Unistream service by SOAP-client and by curl too.

My environment: Ubuntu 15.04, php 5.64

Some history: unistream's support asked us generate certifiate:
makecert.exe -n "CN=some_name" -ss My -r -m 120 -pe -sky exchange -a sha1, then export by mmc end send certificate to them. Ok, we do this and got certificate generated on their side.
I convert their certificate to pem-format and try use is php SoapClient:

```
    $soap = new SoapClient("http://test2.unistream.com:82/wcflib-tc/service.svc?wsdl", [
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'trace' => true,
    'local_cert' => $cert_path,
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2,
    'connection_timeout' => 180,
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE
]);
$data = $soap->GetCountriesChanges(['requestMessage'=>[
        'AuthenticationHeader'=>[
            'AppKey'=>'*',
            'Password'=>'*',
            'Username'=>'*',
        ],
        'UpdateCount'=>1000
    ]]);
```

And i got nothing. I try the same with python soap library, with soapui and got nothing too, timeout.
Ok, i look it with wireshark, and saw that soap client recieve all xsd schemas and etc and then connection interrupt after post request to url: http://test2.unistream.com:82/wcflib-tc/service.svc, just timeout. And i saw only plain http with xml, no packets with ssl.
Ok, i try send post-request on this url:

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 30);
$request_string =
    '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
              xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServiceLib"
              xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServiceLib.Utils"
              xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WcfServiceLib.Dictionaries.Country"
              xmlns:ns4="http://test.unistream.com/wcflib/">
    <env:Body>
        <ns4:GetCountriesChanges>
            <ns4:requestMessage>
                <ns2:AuthenticationHeader>
                    <ns1:AppKey>*</ns1:AppKey>
                    <ns1:Password>*</ns1:Password>
                    <ns1:Username>*</ns1:Username>
                </ns2:AuthenticationHeader>
                <ns3:UpdateCount>1000</ns3:UpdateCount>
            </ns4:requestMessage>
        </ns4:GetCountriesChanges>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
';

$url = 'http://test2.unistream.com:82/wcflib-tc/service.svc';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ['Content-Type: application/soap+xml;', 'Charset=utf-8']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAPATH, "/path");
//my cert
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "/path/local_cert.pem");
//my private key
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "/path/local_key.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, 'passwd');
//api's cert
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, '/path/api_cert.cer'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $request_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CERTINFO, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($result);
echo "\n";
$error = curl_error($ch);
print_r($error);
echo "\n";
```

And i get xml with error: "An error occurred when verifying security for the message."
If i try send request to url: https://test2.unistream.com:82/wcflib-tc/service.svc i got plain html with error 400 and curl error: "error:140770FC:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:unknown protocol"

Support can't help me. They said "we have 10000 working clients, we consult only about high-level api problems and bussines-logic".

Can somebody give me right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have docs for unistream.

I do know that certificates are transport layer. That means that they occur before anything else. But you're connecting to an HTTP URL, not an HTTPS URL and that means you're not using encryption.

Certificates and encryption are not your problem.

However, the URL you pasted is simply not listening for connections on that port.

> $ curl -v http://test2.unistream.com:82/wcflib-tc/service.svc?wsdl
>   *   Trying 94.127.155.67...
>   * Connection timed out after 60001 milliseconds
>   * Closing connection 0 curl: (28) Connection timed out after 60001 milliseconds

You're not using the right address/port number at all.

## Next

1. Get the right url endpoint
2. don't bother with the client certificate unless the endpoint is using HTTPS